# Preg_split matching preset number of instances from right to left

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, preg-split

I'm hoping that there's some way in regex to match certain characters by counting from right to left.

I have a text like the one below where the fields are inconsistent, except that they are delimited by spaces, except the name, which has an indeterminate number of spaces. There are no enclosing marks.

```
NAME WITH SPACES FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3 FIELD4
SECOND NAME WITH SPACES FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3 FIELD4
THIRD NAME WITH SPACES FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3 FIELD4
FOURTH NAME WITH SPACES FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3 FIELD4
FIFTH NAME WITH SOME MORE SPACES FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3 FIELD4
```

I needed to break this up using the last 4 spaces to get the column values and using what's left as the name. I'm about to do this by splitting on all spaces and using the last 4 values in the array, but isn't there a way to do this with regex that I can split the line by the last four spaces? I imagine that it would be looking from right to left in this case.

This particular project is in php using PCRE.

Comment: Reads like you want to get the name part. For this an idea: [`^(.+?)(?:\s+\S+){4}$`](https://regex101.com/r/WdAJ4u/2) [see PHP demo](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxj7AI4CLS6W4pEjBVkHdz9HXVSHcM8RDITjA0dk1WMHN09XHxRBCGUEoYwhlwhXs6uzv56JAkp4QD88gErW4@YcGAVWSpsfTDVWLP5Dl6x/kSoRmdWsursw0jYKi1PT43MSS5Iz4xJwcDXX9OA09bXtNDXurmGLtmGBtzWqTWhX9XHUdBVDgAcn80hJNBTsFA00uBYWCosy8kvgiDZBgtGGsJtBIrv//AQ)

Comment: I actually needed to capture all of it. I ended up using `(.*)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)$` and it captured all the parts. I needed to turn a pdf scrape into a csv. Using the `{4}` instead of typing out the 4 instances is a more concise way to do it and good for learning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this with RegEx.

`\s` is whitespace, `\S` is non-whitespace, `$` represents the end of the line or string.

```php
<?php

$str = "NAME WITH SPACES FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3 FIELD4";

preg_match("/(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)\s(\S+)$/", $str, $matches);

var_dump($matches);

/* OUTPUT:

array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(27) "FIELD1 FIELD2 FIELD3 FIELD4"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "FIELD1"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "FIELD2"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "FIELD3"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "FIELD4"
}

*/
```

Comment: I feel kind of stupid. Your answer is so simple and I was thinking there was something more complicated to it and you got that answer so quickly. 